# Automatically exclude specific files from Included Changes from TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I work with TFS in Visual Studio 2017. I need to automatically exclude specific files, for example *.config, when I checkin my solution. This is because my development and productive areas have differences.

I've [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/vsts/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts) about .tfignore but:

- I have not **Detected** link in Exclude Changes section
- If I manually create in the root of project a .tfignore file which contains `ProjectName\*.config`, it does not work

Comment: Did you delete the .config files that already checked in to source control after creating the tfignore file?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT, no. I want to work with existed files